# Subnet Mask /23 till second octect 255.255.254.0

Tags: ping, broadcast, subnet

I am currently getting subnet Mask ***/23*** till second octect **255.255.254.0.**
My ip address is **10.11.17.111**, and broadcast ip is **10.11.17.254**.

So while pinging the server, is it correct, if we are pining on 
**10.11.16.255**. Since it is not broadcast ip.

Comment: Yes, `10.11.16.255` is pingable from `10.11.17.111. The network `10.11.16.0/23` starts from `10.11.16.0` to `10.11.17.254`

Comment: @CustomX Does not 255 part of 4th octect. And it should be avoided..

Comment: what are you saying ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is if whether or not you can use `10.11.16.255` for a host, given your subnet mask.  Please try re-wording your question if that's not the case.

With your netmask, it is totally acceptable to use `10.11.16.255` for a host.  It's not a broadcast address, nor a network ID.  It's the same as any other IP in this case.

Comment: `It's not a broadcast address, nor a network ID. It's the same as any other IP in this case.` This was my doubt. I was assuming that 0, 255 port numbers in 4th octect are unsafe to use.